# Rearranging a cell array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell, permutation

I'm programming a task for a research study. The problem I have is the following: I have a dictionary with names and with one picture per cell. Like that:

```
nameCues1 = {'Lisa','Anna', 'Sarah', 'Nina', 'resized_1.jpg' };
nameCues2 = {'Emma', 'Lena', 'Gabi', 'Steffi', 'resized_2.jpg' };
```

I have loaded them into a cell array, created a random sequence:

```
nameCuesAll = {nameCues1,nameCues2};

randSeq3 = nameCuesAll(randperm(size(nameCuesAll,2)));
```

Then I loop over it to read in the names of the dictionary and the corresponding picture:

```
for i = 1:numel(nameCuesAll)
    pics3{i} = imread(randSeq3{i}{1,5});
    ind{i}=randSeq3{i}(randperm(numel(randSeq3{i})));
end
```

Then I prompt it on the screen via Psychtoolbox, a toolbox specialized in creating tasks for research, for those who don't know:

```
for j = 1:4
    % (left out unnecessary other functions)
    DrawFormattedText(window,ind{i}(j), 'center', 'center', white, [], [], [], [], [], rect);
end
```

The problem is that the names of the dictionary are not shown in randomized order, and every try I had until now has thrown errors.
The main problem is that I don't know how to correctly randomize/index 
the dictionary-names.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Which MATLAB version are you using? Perhaps it would be simpler for you to use `string` arrays (i.e. `["Lisa","Anna", "Sarah",...]`) instead of cells of chars, as they are more natural to work with...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm using MATLAB 2016. I also thought about switching to another format, cell arrays seem to be very complicated and even problematic for character operations, or I'm not at that level to handle with that good enough.

Comment: Strings were introduced in R2016b, so if you have that, you're in luck. Otherwise, you'll have to use cells, but it's not so bad.. But I think you should make the question much shorter, and ask about what is really bothering you, which is obtaining random permutations from a cell array...

Comment: BTW, I think you wanted to make `nameCuesAll` a long list consisting of the entries of both arrays. If that's the case, you should use `[]` and not `{}` (`nameCuesAll = [nameCues1,nameCues2]`), since `{}` will just create a cell of cells, which will require another level of indexing, and interfere with randomization. You can also look into the [`union`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/union.html) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reorder the elements of a cell array, you should reference elements using `()`:

```
nameCues1 = {'Lisa','Anna', 'Sarah', 'Nina', 'resized_1.jpg' };
rIdx = randperm(numel(nameCues1));
mixedCues = nameCues1(rIdx)
```

which yields for the case of `rIdx = [3 5 1 4 2]`:

```
mixedCues =

  1×5 cell array

    {'Sarah'}    {'resized_1.jpg'}    {'Lisa'}    {'Nina'}    {'Anna'}
```

Then use `mixedCues` instead of `nameCues1`.

See also: [Access Data in Cell Array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).

Comment: @Pry if this answer helped you, please [mark it as "accepted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/). If you have another solution, please post it as your own answer and accept _that_. Accepting is important for other to know that this problem is resolved.